# Access the true buffer of a record in Unicode version of Delphi - ADO

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-2010, ado

Prior to upgrading to Delphi 2010 we were able to extract data stored in a access database string field which actually contains an array of bytes.

This was achieved with something like:

```
  GetMem(buff, 66);
  try
    if Table.FieldByName('BytesInStrField').GetData(buff, True) then //True false ignored anyway
    begin
      Move(Buff^, X, 65);
    end;
  finally
    //
  end;
```

Since we have upgraded even the Buffer seems to stop reading at the first instance of #0#0 (String terminator)

The problem is that this data is no longer accessible to us. I would like to mention it was not myself who decided to put an array of Bytes in a Microsoft Access String Field.

Does anyone have any idea's how I can read the entire filed without truncation, I am trying hard to avoid writing my own Direct Binary Read of the entire DB.

As this is Delphi Accessing Microsoft Access I am using the TADO components.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is the SQL column type of the field you are accessing? VARCHAR?

Comment: @Warren P - Yes the field Type is VarChar which is plain crazy, I am still trying to work out WHY someone thought this was sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GetFieldData methods of TCustomADODataSet are what you need. There are three:

```
function GetFieldData(Field: TField; Buffer: Pointer): Boolean; override;
function GetFieldData(Field: TField; Buffer: Pointer; NativeFormat: Boolean): Boolean; override;
function GetFieldData(FieldNo: Integer; Buffer: Pointer): Boolean; overload; override;
```

The hard work is done in the second one, which is also the one used from the TField.GetData method.

You will need to derive your own descendant of TADODataSet, override the second version of the GetFieldData method with your own version. Call inherited for all other fields, but for your specific BytesInString field, read the buffer yourself and avoid the variant conversion that is done in the TCustomADODataSet.GetFieldData method.

If you want to avoid having to insert your own descendant everywhere, declare an interceptor class in a, for example, ADOInterceptor unit:

```
TADODataSet = class(ADODB.TADODataSet)
public
  function GetFieldData(Field: TField; Buffer: Pointer; NativeFormat: Boolean): Boolean; override;
;
```

And make sure that this unit is used everywhere that ADODB is used and it appears AFTER the ADODB unit in the uses clause.

Comment: I have looked at the GetFieldData and DataConvert but cannot seem to step into it to check whats going on. I may need to just grab the buffer and clone.

Comment: @Reallyethical: If you are using debug dcu's I don't know what is keeping you from stepping into the methods. But grabbing the buffer and cloning sounds ok for you BytesInString field...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Table.FieldByName('BytesInStrField').AsBytes`

Comment: Yes of course, and it gives the right length, but the data after the #0#0 has not been read so all bytes are set to #0 after the first instance of #0#0 which of course is wrong.

Comment: @Reallyethical The AsBytes returns an `TBytes = array of Byte` kind of variable, which may not end with the first #0#0 - or there is an issue with the ADO/VCL translation layer. From the VCL point of view, it will handle #0#0 bytes without any problem. How do you use this AsBytes result?

Comment: If you step through the code you will see that the DB.pas uses a typecase of WideString for the item then fill char for the leghth of field, so has the same affect of missing the rest of the data. I have a feeling this is a more serious driver error and may need to step back down to D7 for this project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Table.GetBlobFieldData()`?